# what is difference between database developer and administrator?

Tags: sql-server

i am a doing graduate degree, and i want to go in database field as i find this subject very interesting. For becoming the DBA ,is there a need of becoming developer first for graduate passout and career beginners.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do careers or certification advice.

Answer (score 2):

At a masters level you should be pretty good at both

Administrator - DBA

- install and configure hardware
  maybe you say that is outside of DBA but most DBA can do hardware
- install and configure database software
- optimize the database configuration
- users, groups, and security
- backups
- index maintenance
- monitor
- need basic SQL just to query systems tables and validate data
- build tables and indexes

Developer

- database design
- write, queries, procedures ....
- index planning and implementation
- build tables
- performance monitoring

Mix

- if you get into partitions and other exotics the database design gets into hardware
- index maintenance - if the DBA is going to do this need to understand indexes
- data load - is this a DBA or developer?
  if it is the DBA then need a lot of developer skills

At a master level should know at least one language / platform.  If you load data there going to be times you need to scrub it row by row.

In a large software shop you may have a developer on a programming team that really only does pure development.   Lets say you are running a packaged application like SAP you would have a DBA that only does DBA and not even have a developer.

Also have application developers that are also database developers.  For big high volume applications the back end developer(s) need to be part database developers.  For small apps that cannot afford a database developer the application developer has no choice but to do it all.

If you are a DBA expect to do some mail, web, group policy, and other system tasks at some point in you career.

Answer (score 0):

ONe does development, the other administrates.

When was the last time you had a developer thinking about things like uptime, high availability, backup retention planning, maintenance windows etc.? Or even know how to plan the disc layout for a high performance server to handle a specific IOPS load (though granted, that often today is "use SSD, finished", bu it was a lot more in times when the fastest you could get were 15k SAS discs).

> For becoming the DBA ,is there a need of becoming developer first

Given that a DBA should know his way around SQL on a professional level, and most developers are not even dilettantes and hardly know more than the most simple syntax, I am more inclined to say that a DBA has to know SQL (assuming most developers know not really anything more than the first page of a SQL book). Technically often a DBA is tasked with writing the really complex SQL because most developers botch any SQL statement longer than 2-3 joins ;) But it really is a  different way of thinking - developers need to know more (as in broader) than a DBA, while a DBA must know his databases inside out and have a lot more operational knowledge, as I showed examples of at the beginning.

Comment: I am a software developer and know a bit more than the simple SQL syntax.

Answer (score -3):

To become a DBA you don't need developing skills. But if you are fast enough to learn that, it'll be an added advantage.

Comment: That is completely wrong or I would rather say your personal opinion